How to import python modules from different folders
My problem is that i have some code on my Z-drive that i want to access in my C-drive. Let me give you a brief intro to the project setup:
On my C-drive I have A.py
On my z-Drive I have two folders "fB" containing the file B.py and folder "fC" containing the file C.py.
In B.py I import a function from C.py using the line:
from ..fC.C import func
This work fine when i run B.py, but the problemn is when i try to import a function from B.py to A.py.
So far i tried to add fB to sys.path, and then import B.py (or a function from it). This kinda works because the error I get, ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package, then happens inside B.py, telling me that A.py "found" B.py, the error however comes from the line
from ..fC.C import func.
I believe this happens because the code will think the relative path ..fC.C should "start" on the C-drive, not in the z-drive as I was hoping, but i rely don't know how to get around it. One solution that works is to use sys.path.append() in all files for all functions i want to add, but this makes the code terrible and hard to follow.
Is there any hope to do something like this? or am i trying to do something fundamentally impossible

You can't simply import files from different folders, You need to make that particular folder as python package. You can do it by adding init.py file. It will be empty. init.py file is used to mark a directory as a Python package. It is used to initialize the package when it is imported.

You have to add an empty file __init__.py into the target directory so that it gets loaded.
- A.py
+ fB
  - __init__.py
  - B.py
+ fC
  - __init__.py
  - C.py

Then from your A.py you will do from fC.C import func.

To some degree this works. but since the A.py is in a different driver i still need to add fB to sys path (which is a ok solution) the biggest downside is that python wont give me the documentation of the functions i use in A.py imported from B.py. In B this does not happen either when i go for the init.py solution that you suggested. Maybe i need to modify the init.py file to make this possible ?
